# How do I blot out too big p-values in a correlation matrix comparing two different subsets?

Tags: r, data-visualization, correlation, r-corrplot

I am doing correlation matrixes in R. I love the `corrplot` package, because of its ease of use and pretty graphics. All the examples on the help page have been done using mirrored rows and columns, but I've been able to do correlation matrixes with different number of columns and rows too.

[The corrplot help page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html).

The package includes an implementation that lets you blot out correlations with too big p-values and it works really well when the matrix is symmetrical, but I can't figure out how to get it to work when I'm doing a correlation matrix with two different subsets.

I'm a newbie when it comes to R, so your help is really appreciated. Thank you in advance!

So these work out fine:

```
corrplot(cor(My30variableSubset, My70variableSubset, use = "complete.obs"), 
    method = "circle", tl.col = "black", tl.cex=0.5, col=col1(200))

CIetPfor30variables <- cor.mtest(My30variableSubset, 0.95)

corrplot(cor(My30variableSubset, use = "complete.obs"), 
    method = "circle", tl.col = "black", tl.cex=0.5, col=col1(200),
    p.mat = CIetPfor30variables[[1]], sig.level = 0.001, insig = "blank")
```

However, this most definetly doesn't:

```
corrplot(cor(MyCoolSubset, MyConcentrationSubset, use = "complete.obs"), 
    method = "circle", tl.col = "black", tl.cex=0.5, col=col1(200),
    p.mat = CIetPfor70variables[[1]], sig.level = 0.001, insig = "blank")
```

The reason being that the cor.mtest-function given in the help, can't deal with this situaltion.

```
cor.mtest <- function(mat, conf.level = 0.95) {
    mat <- as.matrix(mat)
    n <- ncol(mat)
    p.mat <- lowCI.mat <- uppCI.mat <- matrix(NA, n, n)
    diag(p.mat) <- 0
    diag(lowCI.mat) <- diag(uppCI.mat) <- 1
    for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
        for (j in (i + 1):n) {
            tmp <- cor.test(mat[, i], mat[, j], conf.level = conf.level)
            p.mat[i, j] <- p.mat[j, i] <- tmp$p.value
            lowCI.mat[i, j] <- lowCI.mat[j, i] <- tmp$conf.int[1]
            uppCI.mat[i, j] <- uppCI.mat[j, i] <- tmp$conf.int[2]
        }
    }
return(list(p.mat, lowCI.mat, uppCI.mat))
}
```

So I guess I would solve my problem, if I had a function that would do the same as the one above, except that it would take in two different subsets of data and give the p-values & stuff for their correlations.

Here is the R code for two example datasets. In reality, I have a dataset with 15 000 observations for 200 variables and I have taken 70 & 30 variable subsets that I have to use for the correlation matrix. The point is that the cor.mtest -function only accepts one matrix and gives the p-values & stuff of its intercorrelations.

```
variable1 <- c(25, 30, 56)
variable2 <- c(5, 1, 4)
variable3 <- c(160, 110, 220)
variable4 <- c(60, 11, 20)  
variable5 <- c(3, 2, 1)
My30variableSubset <- data.frame(variable1, variable2)
My70variableSubset <- data.frame(variable3, variable4, variable5)
```

Comment: Would you kindly add some sample data using `dput` so that we may have a chance to reproduce your results?

Comment: I added R code for sample data. I do hope that this helps. Thank you for your interest.